# Can Python be avoided with 2D NumPy array in Cython?

Tags: python, python-3.x, cython

I'm trying to minimize Python dependency in a while loop for large data series (>200MM values).

Comparing or setting a 1D NumPy array in Cython can be done completely with C, but doing the same with a 2D NumPy array devolves into expensive Python.

Does anyone know how to avoid this?

Minimal code sample:

```
#!python
#cython: boundscheck=False
#cython: wraparound=False
#cython: cdivision=True

import numpy as np
cimport numpy as np

def sometest():
    cdef np.ndarray[np.float64_t, ndim=1] arr1d = np.zeros((10))
    cdef np.ndarray[np.float64_t, ndim=2] arr2d = np.zeros((10))

    if arr1d[0] > 1:
        arr1d[0] = 1

    if arr2d[0][0] > 1:
        arr2d[0][0] = 1
```

Cython annotation:

[image: Cython annotation]

Expanded Cython annotation:

[image: Expanded Cython annotation]

Thank you in advance for any ideas.

Comment: The preferred way of indexing a 2d array is `arr2d[0, 0]`.

Comment: `arr2d = np.zeros((10))`, this is only a 1d array.

Comment: I just tried it, when you access the array as @hpaulj mentions there is no more yellow at that part.

Comment: Thanks @hpaulj. If you'd care to post that as an answer, I'll accept it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks @hpaulj.

Accessing with arr2d[0,0] instead of arr2d[0][0] indeed does not degrade to Python.

Updated code:

```
#!python
#cython: boundscheck=False
#cython: wraparound=False
#cython: cdivision=True

import numpy as np
cimport numpy as np

def sometest():
    cdef np.ndarray[np.float64_t, ndim=1] arr1d = np.zeros((10))
    cdef np.ndarray[np.float64_t, ndim=2] arr2d = np.zeros((10, 10))

    if arr1d[0] > 1:
        arr1d[0] = 1

    if arr2d[0][0] > 1:
        arr2d[0][0] = 1

    if arr2d[0,0] > 1:
        arr2d[0,0] = 1
```

Cython annotation:

[image: Cython annotation]